# CSS Using em unit. Half the size of an image within a div parent element

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have an image, used as source in the html tag `img`, within a `div`. Using `em` size unit, I would want to resize my image as the half of his parent div box. So I have set img both CSS properties *width* and *height* with a value of `0.5em`.

But as you can see in the following code, the result is not as expected!

```
<div>
   <img src=''>
</div>

html {
   font-size:16px;    
}

div {
   width: 20em;
   height: 20em;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
   border: 1px solid green;
   width: 0.5em;
   height: 0.5em;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/framj00/pz27X/1/

Can you help me please to resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`em`'s are used for proportional measurements. If you use `em` it's going to be based on the root font size, which is `html { font-size: 16px; }`. So `width: 0.5em; height: 0.5em` would actually be 8px.

If you want the image to be 50% of the size of the parent `<div>` you can't use `em` for a measurement, you need to use `%`:

```
img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50%; /* width: 0.5em */
  height: 50%; /* height: 0.5em */
}
```